# Problems with jqplot options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

My sincere apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I've been looking for a while and can't find anything. I'm quite new to javascript and to jqplot and I'm essentially creating my code by copying and modifying bits of sample scripts I've found around the web, so please be as simple and specific in your answers as possible and include some context where relevant.

I'm trying to use the constrainTo option to lock movable points to the y axis. I see in the documentation for jqplot that the command should look something like constrainTo: 'y' but I can't figure out where in the code that should go. My code is below so you can see what I'm trying presently (not working). I've tried numerous other configurations as well, but they all either render the code non-working or just have no effect. Thank you very much for your help!

```
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Limbo</title>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/dist/jquery.min.js">    </script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/dist/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/dist/plugins/jqplot.dragable.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/dist/plugins/jqplot.canvasOverlay.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/dist/plugins/jqplot.BezierCurveRenderer.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="jqPlot/dist/jquery.jqplot.min.css" type="text/css"     media="all" />
 <!--[if IE]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/jqplot/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
 $.jqplot.config.enablePlugins = true;
 $.jqplot('chartdiv',  [[[0,2000],[1,1800],[2,1500],[3,1100],[4,700],[5,300],[6,150],[7,100],[8,60],[9,20],[10,0]]], 
    {
        title: 'Decline Rate',
    seriesDefaults: {
            dragable: {
                constrainTo: 'y'
            }
        }   
    });
 });



 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="chartdiv" style="height:400px;width:300px;"></div>
 </body>

</html>
```

*Final note: of course for you to render this code you'll have to change the src files to wherever they are on your computer, I assume people answering will know that. It's worth noting, though, that this code as is does work on my end, just the constraint isn't working (nor, for that matter, are my attempts to add other options like shadow etc, but that's for another question).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the options doesn't go into seriesDefault, I move the option into series and it just worked.

```
series: [{
    dragable: {
        constrainTo: 'y'
    }
}]
```

Check out the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/finfin/uGqnN/)

Comment: Sure enough that fixed it, thanks. Brought to my attention something odd, though, which is that just including the BezierCurveRenderer breaks everything, even if I don't do anything with it. If all I do is take the working code and add that renderer to the list of scripts at the top, everything stops working. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: There's a bug inside the plugin, check [https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/516/including-beziercurverenderer-plugin-and] for solution. You either have to modify the plugin file or have a seriesDefault in options to solve it.